# RotationAnimation incosistency between emulator and device

Tags: android

I am trying to rotate a bitmap using the code below.

The code works fine on emulator (although the infinite rotation has a small lag but that's another story) but when tested on the actual device the rotation is wrong (wrong pivot I think).

I appreciate any help.

G

public class CircleAnimation extends View {

```
Bitmap bitmap;
Paint paint;
RotateAnimation rotate;
AlphaAnimation blend;
ScaleAnimation scale;
AnimationSet spriteAnimation;

float centerX;
float centerY;
float offsetX;
float offsetY;

public CircleAnimation(Context context) {
      super(context);
      // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

      bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.tile);
        offsetX = bitmap.getWidth() / 2;
        offsetY = bitmap.getHeight() / 2;

        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    //Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.tile);
    //canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, 0, 0, null);
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    if (spriteAnimation == null) {
        centerX = canvas.getWidth() / 2;
        centerY = canvas.getHeight() / 2;
        createAnimation(canvas);
    }
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, centerX - offsetX, centerY - offsetY, paint);
}

private void createAnimation(final Canvas canvas) {

    rotate = new RotateAnimation(0, 360, centerX, centerY);
    rotate.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    rotate.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    rotate.setStartOffset(0);

    spriteAnimation = new AnimationSet(true);
    spriteAnimation.addAnimation(rotate);
    spriteAnimation.setDuration(1000);

    startAnimation(spriteAnimation);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the problem.

I had set the minimum SDK to 8 and target SDK to 8 as well. And I was testing on 15.

Changed the target to 15 and it worked.

:p

G

Comment: Congrats on the fix.  When you are able, please mark your answer as 'accepted' to help others find your solution.  Cheers~